# Can you explain what the app engine context interface is?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am contributing to a Go application where the appengine context interface is used a lot. I have come across a lot of documentation where the context is used as a variable. But I haven't yet found an explanation that I understand of exactly what the context is and what purpose it fills.

What is the go appengine context interface and what is its purpose?

Comment: A package that makes it easy to pass request-scoped values, cancelation signals, and deadlines across API boundaries to all the goroutines involved in handling a request. See the full article at: https://blog.golang.org/context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Context in the paradigm of programming extends beyond just Go.  You should take a look at this thread for a deeper explanation [The term “Context” in programming?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/196475/whats-the-meaning-of-term-context-in-programming).  In terms of App Engine it usually shares information about the request being made i.e. Initiating Server, Client IP, Errors, Timeouts, Is it in the background?, etc.  You can take a look at the [x/net/context](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/context) package for some ideas of how Context can be used.

Hope this helps.